# convert sql query to zend query

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

```
SELECT uls.prod_id,um.prod_image,um.prodname,SUM(msm.points)
FROM tbl_prod_selection AS uls
INNER JOIN tbl_prod_master AS um ON um.prod_id = uls.prod_id
INNER JOIN tbl_admin_prod_selection AS als ON als.user_id = uls.user_id
INNER JOIN tbl_prod_statistics_master AS msm ON (msm.user_id = uls.user_id AND msm.barcode_id = als.barcode_id)
WHERE uls.location_id = "18" AND uls.prod_code = "FLB"
GROUP BY uls.user_id;
```

can any one help to write zend query for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I dont know how to write it. I need help, as I am new to zend framework

Comment: Are you using Zend_Db_Table or just Zend_Db_Adapter?

Comment: I am using zend_db_table. But in the present code I have to write AND condition for Inner join,but I dont know how to write using zend. can u help me in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Zend_Db_Table, then you can assemble Zend_Db_Table_Select like below:

```
$select = $model->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from(array('uls' => 'tbl_prod_selection'), array(
                        'uls.prod_id',
                        'um.prod_image',
                        'um.prodname',
                        'sum' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(msm.points)'),
                ))
                ->join(array('um' => 'tbl_prod_master'), 'um.prod_id = uls.prod_id', array())
                ->join(array('als' => 'tbl_admin_prod_selection'), 'als.user_id = uls.user_id', array())
                ->join(array('msm' => 'tbl_prod_statistics_master'), 'msm.user_id = uls.user_id AND msm.barcode_id = als.barcode_id', array())
                ->where('uls.location_id = ?', '18')
                ->where('uls.prod_code = ?', 'FLB')
                ->group('uls.user_id');
```

Comment: Thanks alot Daniel, that works. But I got error when I include setIntegrityCheck(false) but when I removed it,it worked. Thanks once again.